# Better way to write method either POJO or Utility?

Tags: java, performance, methods, pojo, code-reuse

Which is the better way to create method

1)Create static method in DataUtils.java class

or

2)Create method in pojo Claimheader.java class .

My question is if we create a method in POJO class it will affect any performance .

In our project, we have lots of methods added in POJO class with only get method. So is it good to create get method in POJO class ?
 or

Create method in Utility class.

My boss said to create get method in POJO class instead of create in any utility class.

Please suggest me which is better way to create that .I thought I am right if I create method in DataUtils.java instead of Create in Pojo class.

Please see the code below :

```
public class DataUtils {

    public static String getCurrentResp(Integer currentResp) {
        String val;

        switch (currentResp) {
        case 1:
            val = "Primary";
            break;
        case 2:
            val = "Secondary";
            break;
        case 3:
            val = "Tertiary";
            break;
        default:
            val = currentResp + "th Insurance";
            break;
        }

        return val;

    }
}
```

VS

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "claimheader")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "ClaimHeader.getClaimByClaimNo", query = "SELECT clmhead  FROM ClaimHeader  as clmhead WHERE clmhead.claimNo = :arg1 "),
        @NamedQuery(name = "claimHeader.GetUnPaidClaimByPatient", query = "SELECT clmhead  FROM ClaimHeader  as clmhead WHERE clmhead.insBalance > 0 and clmhead.patientCode = :arg1 "),
        @NamedQuery(name = "claimHeader.GetUnPaidClaimByPatientCode", query = "SELECT clmhead  FROM ClaimHeader  as clmhead WHERE (clmhead.billedAmount = clmhead.balanceAmount) and clmhead.patientCode = :arg1 "),
        @NamedQuery(name = "claimHeader.GetPaidClaimByPatientCode", query = "SELECT clmhead  FROM ClaimHeader  as clmhead WHERE (clmhead.balanceAmount = 0) and clmhead.patientCode = :arg1 "),
        @NamedQuery(name = "claimHeader.GetUnPaidAndPaidClaimByPatientCode", query = "SELECT clmhead  FROM ClaimHeader  as clmhead WHERE clmhead.patientCode = :arg1 ") })
public class ClaimHeader extends BaseEntityByCode {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @NotNull(message = "Claim No cannot be empty")
    private Integer claimNo;

    private Integer currentResp;


    public Integer getCurrentResp() {
        return currentResp;
    }

    public void setCurrentResp(Integer currentResp) {
        this.currentResp = currentResp;
    }

    public String getCurrentRespDesc() {

        String value = "";
        if (currentResp == null)
            return "";

        switch (currentResp) {
        case -1:
            value = "Patient";
            break;
        case 1:
            value = "Primary";
            break;
        case 2:
            value = "Secondary";
            break;
        case 3:
            value = "Tertiary";
            break;
        default:
            value = currentResp.toString() + "th Insurance";
            break;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

}

Comment: It is simpler to do `claimHeader.getCurrentRespDesc()` than `DataUtils.getCurrentResp(claimHeader.getCurrentResp())` ... and since the description depends on the value of `ClaimHeader`, this should be in it. By the way, you should use enums instead of this solution.

Comment: "is it good to create get method in POJO clas" ... this is bit of a non-sense question imho. A getter is supposed to return a property of an instance, so it should be part of the pojo. If it's not returning a property proper to the instance of the class, it shouldn't be a getter

Comment: @AxelH Any idea to create enum class

Comment: @Sitansu whether you return an enum or a String is not really relevant. Axel is right, you may not be returning an instance member of the classes instance, but you do return a value that is specific for the instance of the class. keep it in the class itself.

Comment: @AxelH in this case it's not possible to use an enum, because there are only four fixed values and the rest is a compound String with the int-value and "_th Insurance_"

Comment: @devpuh agree. An `Enum` is useful for functions where valid mappings can be contained in a small discrete set. In this case we have a function with no bounds, making it inappropriate.

Comment: *"My question is if we create a method in POJO class it will affect any performance ."* **Never** choose a certain syntax or construct for performance consideration unless you have **proven by measurement** that you actually *have* a performance problem **and** the code in question is really the bottleneck **and** the alternative really solves the problem. Stay with the version that is *most readable*  and/or expresses *your intent* best.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with your boss. Not a pro about the performance here, but I do not think any of these will affect your performance in a relevant way.

What is more important is the code logic itself. Utils classes should provide external methods with additional, convenience functions (just like Integer.parseInt() method, or the whole Apache Commons lib). Getting information about the component itself is the part of this object's logic and should be placed within it.